# Swagger and ServiceStack 4.0

Tags: c#, servicestack, swagger

First, I'll ask my question, then explain our problems found during testing. We can't seem to access the Swagger API on the `resources` route using ServiceStack 4.0. Is this still supported?

We're starting a greenfield project and are investigating ServiceStack. As recommended, we're using version 4.0 from http://ServiceStack.net. We've established a "Security" service and verified that `/Security/User/username` correctly returns our information about the user. End to end tests of ServiceStack are working great.

As we go forward, we also want to document our API using Swagger. It appears in our tests that the `resources` route is no longer supported, or at least is not working, in version 4.0. We've downloaded all the sample projects for guidance and they're all using ServiceStack 3.9.33, so not much luck using the samples. We've tried these local URLs for the Swagger resources snapshot:

```
localhost:85/resources
localhost:85/api/resources (with routing changes in the web.config
localhost:85/security/resources
localhost:85/api/security/resources (with routing changes in the web.config)
```

All with no luck. What are we missing?

Here is our AppHost class:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost()
      : base("API Services", typeof(SecurityService).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
      Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
      Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

      container.RegisterValidators(typeof(UserValidator).Assembly);
    }
}
```

And the relevant code from our Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new AppHost().Init();
}
```

We've got the lastest of all packages using NuGet and Visual Studio 2013. Any guidance for ServiceStack newbies is appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable the Swagger plug-in in your `AppHost`? That detail is easy to miss. Here's what you need in your `AppHost.Configure` method: `Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());`

Comment: Also you can visit the `/metadata` page in your web browser, and you should see `ResourceRequest` and `Resources` operations if Swagger is correctly configured.

Comment: Yes, I configured the feature in AppHost. I don't see ResourceRequest or Resources in my metadata page. What I see are only my 3 operations.  I updated the question with the relevant code.

Comment: What happens when you go to `/swagger-ui/index.html`?

Comment: @Scott, I get the basic Swagger page, but no matter what value I enter into the API text box, I get errors, usually "Can't read swagger JSON from localhost:85/resources" or a console error where the data of the rawResponse is "undefined" in the Swagger API build method (from swagger.js).

Comment: What specific version of the Swagger plugin are you using? The most recent is 4.0.5. Have you tried a previous version say 4.0.2? https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/

Comment: @mohrtan I notice that 5 days ago there was a [fix specifically for SwaggerFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/5007ed7bf65b0f2f1b3742273cd0fdbe26a6b592). Perhaps it's related. What happens if you try to do `appHost.RegisterService(typeof(SwaggerResourcesService), new[] { "/resources" });`?

Comment: @Scott, downgrading to 4.0.3 worked. I then saw `Resources` in the metadata and the Swagger UI page worked. I then re-upgraded to 4.0.5 and it still works. At this point, the only difference was that I installed packages via the NUGET console (worked) instead of the UI (didn't work). Maybe an issue with Visual Studio? Thanks to all for the help. I'm rolling along now.

Answer (score 3):

I wish the solution were smarter than this, if only so that I felt that I understood the problem, but removing and then reinstalling all ServiceStack packages via the package management console solved the issue. Thanks to all who helped me to debug.